# How to add HashSet element to object in Arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

I want to add a `HashSet String` (Doctor Specialty) to an object in my ArrayList of doctors but can't access Specialist (Doctor Type) class from the Driver. Specialist doctor class is a subclass of RegisteredDoctor which is a subclass of Doctor.

I have added specialisms when adding the specialist doctors but now can't add another without adding another object to the arraylist. The Doctor and RegisteredDoctor classes are abstract also.

I can add specialism through adding the specialist doctor object

```
specialism.add(ScannerInput.validNextLine("Enter the Doctor's area of Speciality:  "));

doctors.addDoctor(new Specialist(name, dob, gender, address, contactNumber, isQualifiedInIreland, qualifications, specialism));
```

I have these getter and setter methods but can't access them from the Driver.

```
public HashSet<String> getSpecialism() {
    return specialism;
}

public void setSpecialism(HashSet<String> specialism) {
    this.specialism = specialism;
}
```

I need to be able to add multiple specialisms to existing specialist doctor objects.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly the problem is. Please add more details of what's not working.

Comment: What's a `Driver`?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, tough to explain correctly without showing entire code. The Driver is my main class which has the system outputs. I'm trying to add multiple hashset elements to an object but because the objects super class is abstract I can't access it directly using hashset.add() A better question might be How do I access a class that is at the bottom of a three layer hierarchy? The two layers above it are abstract

Answer (score 0):

This was very badly explained (Happens when you don't know exactly what your looking for). The instanceOf operator was the answer I was looking for, enabled me to get access to the setSpecialism method in one of my subclasses.

```
    int index = ScannerInput.readNextInt("Enter Index of Doctor you want to update Specialisms: ");
    HashSet<String> spec = new HashSet<>();

    if (doctors.getDoctor(index) instanceof Specialist) {
        int num = ScannerInput.readNextInt("Enter how many Specialisms you want to add: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            String specUpdate = ScannerInput.validNextLine("Enter Specialism: ");
            spec.add(specUpdate);
        }
    }
    ((Specialist) doctors.getDoctor(index)).setSpecialism(spec);
```